# LWUIT, How to create a custom label for form title

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I want to know how to create a label that contains two icons, one on each side and set it as the title bar for the form element (LWUIT widgets).

[image]

Comment: can you plz explain your question in little more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form has a function to get a titleArea then you can put some components what you want.

```
Form f = new Form();
Container c = f.getTitleArea();
Label iconLabel1 = new Label("leftIcon");//using Image
Label iconLabel2 = new Label("rightIcon");//using Image
c.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, iconLabel1);
c.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, iconLabel2);
```

Comment: Thanks u Yahan, both your solution and that of Shai Almog work.

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a component to the north portion of the screen which is the recommended way that will work properly and won't break for newer versions of LWUIT/[Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/).

When you don't set a title it will just work and you can give it the Title UIID. LWUIT 1.5 and newer have a TitleArea container but I suggest you stay away from it since CodenameOne customizes it quite allot for iOS/Android 4.x etc.

Comment: If I add a component to the north portion of the screen, when scrolling, the component will move out of the screen, and I don't want this to happen.

Comment: form.setScrollable(false); containerInCenterPosition.setScrollableY(true);

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setTitleComponent(Label title)` method.

---

**EDIT :**

Derive the `Label` class and implement the `paint` method where you can use the `Graphics` method to draw `Image`s and texts. Also set the label's text position to `Label.CENTER` .

Comment: I know how to set a label for the title of a form using 'setTitleComponent(Label title)' . My problem is that i don't know how to customize a label so that it contains two icons, one on each side and a text in the center.